# Custom external itemRenderer is receiving null objects from dataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, null, flex3, itemrenderer

I have a custom external itemRenderer which I use to display items in a mx:List. The dataProvider is an Array that contains 4 attributes per element. It seems as if the itemRenderer is, in fact, getting the Array because it displays 4 items(the amount of items in the Array) but the items are displayed as "[object Object]".

Here is my itemRenderer...

```
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(type="classes.events.RemoveEntryEvent", name="removeProject")]
</mx:Metadata>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import classes.events.RemoveEntryEvent;

        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        override public function set data (value:Object):void{
            super.data = value;
            //Alert.show(value.toString());
        }

         public function button_clickHandler():void {
            var alertListener:Function = function(closeEvent:CloseEvent):void{
                if (closeEvent.detail == Alert.YES){
                    //dispatchEvent(new RemoveEntryEvent(RemoveEntryEvent.REMOVE_PROJECT, true, false, data));
                }
            } 

            var myAlert:Alert = Alert.show("Are you sure you want to remove yourself from this project?", 
                "Remove Project", 
                (Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL),
                null, alertListener);

            myAlert;
        }      

        private function text_clickHandler():void{
            Alert.show("inside text_clickHandler()");
        }



    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<!-- The mx:Text should display a hand maybe when rolledOver: !buttonMode, -->
<mx:Text id="text" width="85%" text="{data}" fontThickness="5" click="text_clickHandler()"/>
<mx:Button id="removeButton" label="Remove" fontSize="9" width="63" verticalCenter="0" fontWeight="normal" x="329" 
           height="17" click="button_clickHandler()"></mx:Button>


</mx:Canvas>
```

When I step through the set data function, the 'value:Object' is null! But again, it is displaying the correct amount of items.

Here is my mxml code in which my mx:List is contained...

```
<mx:TitleWindow y="10" width="550" height="342" layout="absolute" title="LIST OF PROJECTS" cornerRadius="4" id="listOfProjects_panel" horizontalCenter="0"> 
    <mx:List alternatingItemColors="{altColors}" x="65.5" y="30" width="399" height="232" backgroundColor="#F8F8F8" fontSize="12" dataProvider="{xmlSimpleArray}"
                             id="list_of_projects_master" initialize="listInitializer()" useRollOver="false" selectable="false">
    </mx:List>
    <mx:Button y="270" label="Refresh List" width="130" x="334.5" id="auth_btn_master0" fontWeight="normal"/>
    <mx:Label x="65.5" y="10" text="Click To Select A Project:" fontWeight="bold"/>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Here is the initializer in my mx:Script...

```
private function listInitializer():void{
            //list_of_projects_master.dataProvider = xmlSimpleArray;
            list_of_projects_master.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ProjectListRenderer);
            list_of_projects_master.addEventListener(RemoveEntryEvent.REMOVE_PROJECT, updateXML);
        }
```

If anymore information is needed to assess the issue, please let me know

Comment: btw, here is my Array....[Bindable]
                          public var xmlSimpleArray:Array;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the below line in itemrenderer

```
<mx:Text id="text" width="85%" text="{data}" fontThickness="5" click="text_clickHandler()"/>
```

shoul be like

```
<mx:Text id="text" width="85%" text="{data.labelfieldname}" fontThickness="5" click="text_clickHandler()"/>
```

hope this helps.